# pkgDep does not find dependencies for my package

Tags: r

I'm trying to deploy my R package on a local repository with its dependencies.

The idea is to share this repository with others in my company so they can use my functions. They would also be able to install my package dependencies from the local repository, which is faster than downloading them from CRAN and prevents proxy problems.

I'm using miniCRAN and drat for this.

Let's start from a simple example:

I created a new `mytestpkg` package in RStudio.

It contains only one R file (hello.R) that imports ggplot2:

```
#' Hello function
#'
#' @return NONE
#' @export
#' @import ggplot2
#'
#' @examples hello()
hello <- function() {
  print("Hello, world!")

  x <- seq(0, 10, by = 0.1)
  y <- cos(x)
  my.df <- data.frame(x, y)
  ggplot(my.df, aes(x, y)) + geom_line() + geom_point()
}
```

I configured the project options so that ROxygen generates the NAMESPACE file. Here is what it contains:

```
# Generated by roxygen2: do not edit by hand

export(hello)
import(ggplot2)
```

Now I install the package in my repository:

```
require(miniCRAN)
# Generate the documentation and update the NAMESPACE file
devtools::document(roclets=c('rd', 'collate', 'namespace', 'vignette'))
# Build the package
package.source.path <- devtools::build()
# Insert the package in my local repo
drat::insertPackage(package.source.path,
                    repodir = "C:/path/to/my/repo",
                    action = "prune")
# Add my local repo to the list of repos
options(repos = c(CRAN = "https://ftp.igh.cnrs.fr/pub/CRAN/",
                  MyRepo = "file:///C:/path/to/my/repo"))
# Find dependencies
pkgs <- c("mytestpkg")
pkgList <- pkgDep(pkgs, type="source")
```

The problem here is that pkgList only contains one string:

```
> pkgList
[1] "mytestpkg"
```

So if I call makeRepo, it will only copy my package and not its dependencies.

What did I do wrong?

## Edit:

Apparently, depPkg looks for imports that are in the DESCRIPTION file, not the NAMESPACE file.

So I need to manually edit the DESCRIPTION file each time I have a new import?
That's inconvenient... Couldn't Roxygen do this?

Answer (score 1):

To specify a package dependency, you can use :

```
devtools::use_package("ggplot2")
```

It will then be automatically added to you DESCRIPTION file.

Comment: That's true, but it's far from automatic: I need to read my whole package to find the imports I use, or I need to copy them from the NAMESPACE file. Which is the same as copying them from the NAMESPACE file to the DESCRIPTION file.

Comment: Of course. As far as I know, there is no way to scan all your R files and put the used packages in the DESCRIPTION file. But if ever you succeed to code that, I'll be the first to use it :)